# Source control workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, workspace

I need to share Eclipse C++ projects in the team. We have some library projects that are used to build the product as well as all testers. Therefore we have to put all these projects into a Eclipse workspace to build the targets and to debug the testers and the product.

Since there is a bunch of projects it's cumbersome to add all or even remove/rename projects on every workstation to the workspace. How can we share and synchronize the workspace, preferrable with our revision control system?

EDIT: We use Surround SCM and have installed the Surround SCM Team plug-in.

Answer (score -2):

You want a single pc/server to act as repository for your projects. Drop a copy of subversion on it. There's a subversion client that you can integrate into eclipse on all the other machines. when setup you all work on a local copy and submit changes to the main subversion server.

You will need to decide on which version of the code you install as the initial base. Then on each PC setup a new working folder (that differs from the current work) and "get latest" finally overwriting the project with changed code in the old project.

You may want to get the free copy of Jira and tie that into your subversion so that only work with a valid reference can be checked in.

Comment: The question was about the workspace. Project's revision control appears as solved. But this does not make the projects appear in workspace.